# Unidecoding elements in PyArrow column

Tags: python, pyarrow

I want to avoid to loop through all elements of a PyArrow column and apply `unidecode` function from the `unidecode` package in order to create a list of unidecoded elements that will be converted into a PyArrow column so I was wondering if PyArrow has a function that does this in a more efficient way since this requires a lot of time for columns with a length greater than 1 million. I was looking at the 'compute' package of PyArrow but I didn't find anything useful. This is what I am doing now:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
import pyarrow
import pyarrow.compute as pc


pc_value_counts = pc.value_counts(tmp_column)

value_counts = dict()

for record in pc_value_counts:

    record_py = record['values'].as_py()

    if isinstance(record_py, str) and not record_py.isdigit():
           unique_value = unidecode(record_py)
    else:
           unique_value = record_py

    value_counts[unique_value] = value_counts.get(unique_value, 0) + record['counts'].as_py()

table = pyarrow.table([pyarrow.array(value_counts.keys()), pyarrow.array(value_counts.values())],
                              schema=pyarrow.schema([pyarrow.field('unique_values', pyarrow.string()),
                                                     pyarrow.field('value_counts', pyarrow.int32())]))
```

where `tmp_column` is a PyArrow column

Answer (score 0):

Could you express what you want to do with one of the kernels here: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/compute.html?#string-transforms ?

Comment: Nope, none of them does what the unidecode function does https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/0.04.1/

Comment: I would then propose you open a feature request ticket here: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/dev/developers/bug_reports.html
This would require C++ changes in Arrow.